# POST request to Django Model Formset with Vuejs front-end

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using Django to build a back-end of my project and Vuejs to build the front-end.

I have defined my models in Django and have used Django forms to save data to the models. For a single form, I just pass a JSON object in the body of the POST request. This works perfectly fine.

But now I need to save multiple records at the same time. I found that Django model formsets can do this. However, I am not able to figure out how to format the POST request. The Django documentation assumes that I'll be using Django templates (which is quite annoying), and therefore says nothing about the format of the request itself.

The application is an API documentation tool and I need to allow the user to define the params of the API. As of now, I have the following:

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from docs.models import ApiParams

ParamsFormSet = modelformset_factory(ApiParams, exclude=('param_id',))

def create_params(request):
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body = json.loads(body_unicode)
    formset = ParamsFormSet(body)
    instaces = formset.save()
    return HttpResponse(instances)
```

I called this API with the following data:

```
[
    {
        "api": 2,
        "param_name": "param1",
        "param_type": "string",
        "param_required": true,
        "param_sample": "param"
    },
    {
        "api": 2,
        "param_name": "param2",
        "param_type": "numeric",
        "param_required": false,
        "param_sample": "3"
    }
]
```

But this results in the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /create-params/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\docs\views.py", line 47, in create_api_params
    if formset.is_valid():
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 308, in is_valid
    self.errors
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 288, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 329, in full_clean
    for i in range(0, self.total_form_count()):
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 112, in total_form_count
    return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max)
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 91, in management_form
    if not form.is_valid():
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 376, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 388, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "D:\Documents\django\api-docs\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 258, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

P.S. My question doesn't have anything to do with Vuejs, that was mentioned only so that people don't suggest Django template solutions. I made the above POST request with Postman, haven't even integrated theh API with my front end.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using Django Rest Framework? I mean, you're swimming against the stream, because forms / formsets are made for HTML. You use Vue, so you can't sync a dynamic formset from Django with Vue. It's ... not a good marriage. Vue and DRF on the other hand, is very common.

Comment: I just started learning Django and Vue last month. I knew Python and SQL already. So in my first project, I just built some APIs without using models or forms using raw SQL queries. In this second project I started using models and forms. So I was trying to avoid having to learn another extensive library at the same time. 
But many people have suggested this, so I guess I'll just have to dive into it.
Before I got into this, my understanding was that Django is a tool to build APIs, I'm only now starting to understand that DRF is quite essential if my application is based on REST APIs.

Comment: Django is a tool to build websites. The default mode is render HTML via templates / views + forms / models. DRF is a tool to turn Django into a API, where the frontend is expected to be offloaded to a different application or even be non-existent. If you want to go lightweight in the backend ([required reading](https://hackernoon.com/use-django-or-end-up-building-a-django-6cce65eb7255)) then you could opt for Flask or Pyramid.

Comment: I've been trying a few tutorials with DRF. So far it's pretty confusing. The syntax is not as straightforward as Django itself. I still don't understand the need for DRF as Django already does everything that DRF does. Why can't Django extend the functionality to use it as a REST API building tool as well, rather than having a third party library reimplement the same features?

Comment: Sorry, this is getting out of scope. I don't know what tutorials you've followed and what's confusing. Half of DRF is class based views identical to Django's. The other is serialization. Once you get serialization, you don't need to worry about turning models into json, reading json into models, return json responses instead of HTML and all that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I guess it is just the unfamiliarity of it. I just learnt Django forms and then discovered they're not the right tool for my problem. So it starts to get a bit confusing when you're looking at so many new things at the same time. I'll give it a try, hopefully I'll figure it out in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's see if we do this in DRF. I'm assuming your ApiParam model is this:

```py
_param_types = ["string", "integer", "array", "object"]
PARAM_TYPE_CHOICES = [(t, t) for t in _param_types]

class ApiParam(models.Model):
    api = models.ForeignKey(Api, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="parameters")
    param_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    param_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=PARAM_TYPE_CHOICES)
    param_required = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    param_sample = models.TextField()
```

The serialization would be:

```
class ApiParamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ApiParam
        fields = [  # Explicit > Implicit
            "param_name",
            "param_type",
            "param_required",
            "param_sample"
        ]
```

Judging from the formset in the title, what your intention with the payload seems to be is to update an Api model with additional parameters, which is a reverse foreign key or perhaps even a ManyToMany.

In this case, it's better to structure the payload as:

```
{
    "api": 2,
    "parameters": [
        {
            "param_name": "param1",
            "param_type": "string",
            "param_required": true,
            "param_sample": "param"
        },
        {
            "param_name": "param2",
            "param_type": "numeric",
            "param_required": false,
            "param_sample": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Your ApiSerializer would be:

```py
class ApiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    api = serializers.IntegerField(source='api_id')
    parameters = ApiParamSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Api
        fields = ["api", "parameters"]
```

And your view:

```py
class ApiUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ApiSerializer
```

And we should be done. As you can see this is all declarative. And the heavy lifting is done by Django / DRF. It takes a bit to get used to, but it's pretty straight forward once the quarter drops.